# How to stop a 'turtle.onscreenclick' function by pressing a key?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, turtle-graphics

I've made a simple program which allows you to click on the screen to draw stuff using the turtle. Every point you move to is recorded in an array. I want to write this array to a text file using JSON when the user is finished drawing something.

```py
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

pastMovementsX = [0]
pastMovementsY = [0]

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 350)
screen.screensize(600, 600)

def move(x, y):
        moveto = turtle.goto(x, y)
        pastMovementsX.append(turtle.xcor())
        pastMovementsY.append(turtle.ycor())

turtle.onscreenclick(move)
```

Any code after `turtle.onscreenclick()` will not run. I assume that it keeps checking for a click on the screen and therefore can't continue with the program.

I've tried a couple things. Notably threading and multiprocessing to do this. It didn't work and after a bit of research it seems the turtle module doesn't like or work well with threading/multiprocessing.

How would I get the program to stop `turtle.onscreenclick()` and continue with further code after a keypress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any code after turtle.onscreenclick() will not run. I assume that it
>   keeps checking for a click on the screen and therefore can't continue
>   with the program.

You question is invalid as your premise is incorrect:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def move(x, y):
        moveto = turtle.goto(x, y)
        pastMovementsX.append(x)
        pastMovementsY.append(y)

pastMovementsX = [0]
pastMovementsY = [0]

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 350)
screen.screensize(600, 600)

turtle = Turtle()

screen.onclick(move)

turtle.circle(50)

screen.mainloop()
```

The `onclick()` method sets a handler function and continues on to the next statement, it doesn't *check* for anything.  That's done by the tkinter event loop which is transfered to by the final `mainloop()` call in the program.

My guess is you're not thinking correctly about the sequence of actions your code plans to undertake and describing those might help to address your actual problem.